# Using a ternary if the condition block is short

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a piece of that is working, but I've been advised that I should use a ternary if the condition block is short.

```
module PayerContractsHelper

  def showPayerContractRate(val)
    json_val = JSON.parse(val)
    if(json_val['amount'].present?)
      "display:block"
    else
      "display:none"
    end
  end

end
```

How exactly can I make this a ternary with this piece of code? I assume it will be less code and more precise. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5):

The ternary conditions is defined as:

```
condition ? if-true : if-false
```

In your case the following code

```
json_val = JSON.parse(val)
if json_val['amount'].present?
  "display:block"
else
  "display:none"
end
```

will become

```
JSON.parse(val)['amount'].present? ? "display:block" : "display:none"
```

or

```
json_val = JSON.parse(val)
json_val['amount'].present? ? "display:block" : "display:none"
```

The following version is the most readable to me

```
module PayerContractsHelper

  def showPayerContractRate(val)
    json_val = JSON.parse(val)
    "display:" + (json_val['amount'].present? ? "block" : "none")
  end

end
```

Also note that the Ruby naming convention for methods is `underscore_case`:

```
module PayerContractsHelper

  def show_payer_contract_rate(val)
    json_val = JSON.parse(val)
    "display:" + (json_val['amount'].present? ? "block" : "none")
  end

end
```

Comment: Personally, I'm not a big fan of the conditional operator. Is `"display:" + (json_val['amount'].present? ? "block" : "none")` really more readable than `"display:" + if json_val['amount'].present? then "block" else "none" end`?